# TFS 2015 No agent can be found with following capabilities: msbuild, java, sonar qube

Tags: tfs, msbuild, sonarqube, tfs-2015

I've succeeded build with TFS 2015 Using MSbuild task. Now I've added Sonar qube tasks (SonarQube for MSBuild - Begin Analysis & End Analysis), find the Sonarqube settings below:

[image]

**1. What is the Project key & how do we get it? I just gave Project Name as key.**

Immediately on build  trigger threw error/warning:

> There are issues with the request or definition that may prevent the
>   build from running:No agent could be found with the following
>   capabilities: msbuild, java, msbuild, java. Queue the build anyway?

On Trigger Build further, Build failed with following error

> No agent found in pool which satisfies the specified demands: 
>   msbuild
>   java 
>   msbuild 
>   msbuild java Agent.Version -gtVersion 1.94.0

On cross-checking, i see that under General section in Build definition : Demand for MSBuild & java exists.

**2. Am i correct or missing anything/settings?**

[image]

I've configured Service Endpoint for SonarQube also. Find the screen shot below:

[image]

Please suggest on my error & queries highlighted.

Comment: What about the agent version? Is it at least version 1.94?

Comment: Agent Version is 1.95.4

Answer (score 2):

When adding new task which required agent capabilities you need to add it to the agent.

[image]

The capabilities must be installed on the build servers where the agents are located.

**UPDATE:**

I just installed sonar qube on my test environment. 
I got the same exception as you did, fixed it by installing java and msbuild .
Check,if those capabilities exists under your agent :

[image]

Comment: Which capability needs to be installed/configured for sonarqube over here and how?

Comment: msbuild, java, msbuild, java. as you mentioned above .

Comment: how to add these in configuration? Please suggest on path specification for msbuild, java

Comment: Install Visual Studio and java on your build server, then restart the build agent. Restarting the build agent will capture the added Capabilities.

Comment: Thanks Amit - Need sometime to try out. Can you specify which version of Java is apt?

Comment: i installed the latest version.Hope this helped you :)

Comment: I have installed java then solved the issue. Thank you @AmitBaranes

Comment: @NoorAllSafaet Glad I could help

Comment: facing same issue tried all the stuff but no result